# Counting 0`s, 1`s, 99`s and NA`s for each variable in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 118 variables with `0's`, `1's` `99's` and `NA's`. I need count for each variable how many `99's`, `NA's`, `1's` and `0's` there is (the `99` is "not apply", the `0` is "no", the `1` is "yes" and the `NA` is "No answer"). I try to do this with `table` function but it works with vectors, how can I do it for all the set of variables?

There is a little reproducible example of the data frame:

```
forest<-c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,NA,0,NA,0,99,99,1,0,NA)
water<-c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,99,99,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,NA,NA,99,1,0)
rain<-c(1,NA,1,0,1,99,99,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,NA,99,99,1,1)
fire<-c(1,0,0,0,1,99,99,NA,NA,NA,1,0,1,0,0,NA,99,99,1,1)

df<-data.frame(forest,water,rain,fire)
```

And I need write in a data frame the result for variable, like this:

```
    forest    water    rain    fire
1    8         5        8       6
0    7         6        6       6
99   2         3        4       4
NA   3         6        2       4
```

Comment: `lapply(df, table)`. Or `sapply(df, table)` for **s**implified output rather than a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't find a good dupe, so here's my comment as an answer:

A data frame is really a list of columns. `lapply` will apply a function to every item in the input (every column, in the case of a data frame) and return a list with each result:

```
lapply(df, table)
# $forest
# 
#  0  1 99 
#  7  8  2 
# 
# $water
# 
#  0  1 99 
#  6  5  3 
# 
# $rain
# 
#  0  1 99 
#  6  8  4 
# 
# $fire
# 
#  0  1 99 
#  6  6  4
```

`sapply` is like `lapply`, but it will attempt to **s**implify the result instead of always returning a `list`. In both cases, you can pass along additional arguments to the function being applied, like `useNA = "always"` to `table` to have `NA` included in the output:

```
sapply(df, table, useNA = "always")
#      forest water rain fire
# 0         7     6    6    6
# 1         8     5    8    6
# 99        2     3    4    4
# <NA>      3     6    2    4
```

For *lots* more info, check out [R Grouping functions: sapply vs. lapply vs. apply. vs. tapply vs. by vs. aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3505701/903061)

---

To compare with some other answers: `apply` is similar to `lapply` and `sapply`, but it is intended for use with matrices or higher-dimensional arrays. The only time you should use `apply` on a *`data.frame`* is when you need to apply a function *to each row*. For functions on data frame columns, prefer `lapply` or `sapply`. The reason is that `apply` will coerce the data frame to a `matrix` first, which can have unintended consequences if you have columns of different classes.

Answer (score 2):

```
rbind(sapply(df,table),"NA"=sapply(df, function(y) sum(is.na(y))))
   forest water rain fire
0       7     6    6    6
1       8     5    8    6
99      2     3    4    4
NA      3     6    2    4
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
tables <- apply(df, 2, FUN = table)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a way to do it in one fell swoop.

apply(df, 2, table)

apply(df, 2, function(x){ sum(is.na(x)) })

Answer (score 1):

As the variables are factors, you should first turn them into it:

```
df <- lapply(df, as.factor)
```

And then, summary your `data.frame`:

```
sapply(df, summary)
```

The factor method for the `summary()` function counts each level of it.